# TestCase for testing Optparse bad/missing argument

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to test the options/arguments being passed to my code and their expected outcome. I am using `Optparse` to accept these arguments. Right now the code I am testing simply executes

`parser.error("Some message")`

when I am missing an argument or if I passed a bad argument.

Upon entering a bad argument. How can I test for this? Which method within `unittest.TestCase` do I use to assert that `parser.error()` occurred?

Comment: [*"In either case, `optparse` handles the error the same way: it prints the program’s usage message and an error message to standard error and exits with error status 2."*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#how-optparse-handles-errors) - you probably can't test for this, as the code under test quits Python.

Comment: Partially off-topic (not using optparse), but I am using `click` package, which offers `from click.testing import CliRunner`. That can be used to invoke the commands and evaluate results. More in [click.testing docs](http://click.pocoo.org/5/testing/).

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention on mock module:

```
import mock
import unittest


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_parser(self):
        with mock.patch('path.to.your.function') as error_mock:
            call_your_code()
            self.assertEqual(error_mock.called, True)
```